# JMP instruction does not compile using MASM32

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, opcode, masm32

Here's the MASM code :

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
include \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc

includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib

.code

start:
jmp Debut

Suite:
mov esi, 7706304eh
call esi
jmp 00000000h

Debut:
xor eax, eax
push eax
call Suite
db "C:\WINDOWS\system32\calc.exe"

end start
```

As you can see I need to use a special JMP instruction corresponding to the opcode 'E9'.
However it seems that the syntax is not correct using MASM.

I have th e following error message :

```
A2076 : Jump destination must specify a label
```

I know that 'jmp _label' works but it's not what I'm looking for here. So I tried with another way like "jmp dword ptr ds: 00000000h ' or ' mov eax, 00000000h; jmp eax 'but the opcode generated does not match 'E9'. I'm really lost in front of that situation. Does anyone can help me, please ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve with your "jmp 0" instruction?  it doesn't make any sense in the program you offer.   (If you just want to code a jmp, try "jmp $"; when executed, this will cause the program to hang).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Once this code will be compiled I will replace the 00000000h address by a valid one. The presence of the address in the ASM code is here to keep the same number of opcode once the code is compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP says: *Once this code will be compiled I will replace the 00000000h address by a valid one. The presence of the address in the ASM code is here to keep the same number of opcode once the code is compiled*

Then what you probably want to write is:

```
my_jump: 
    jmp   near ptr $  ; produces a 4 byte long relative jump instruction that jmps-to-self
```

and when you know the target address which you want it to jump, and have loaded that address in eax, you can code:

```
    mov    eax, ....      ; desired target address
    sub    eax, offset my_jump+4 ; compute relative offset for jmp to get to target
    mov    dword ptr my_jump+1, eax ; update the jump instructio
```

This should work.  It has the disadvantage of being self-modifying code, which may not be allowed under your OS, and if is allowed, is not accepted as good practice.

An easier and better approach is to place the desired target location in a well-known data location, and modify your code to use that:

```
    .data
    target_location  dword   0   ; filled in later

    .code

     Suite:
     mov esi, 7706304eh     ; hardwiring this constant is bad practice, too, but you didn't ask about that
     call esi
     mov   esi, target_location
     jmp   esi
```

This code is not self modifying, and this kind of trick in assembler is pretty common.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the first solution you have proposed generate the opcode 'E8' and I'd like to have 'E9'. The second one it's the same thing and I'm not allowed to have a .data section in my code. Thank you very much anyway for the complete answer.

Comment: If you want a short jmp for the first case, then code "jmp short $". You'll have to change the relative offset computation a bit to tmatch.  "not allowed to have a data section"? By who?

Comment: I'm programming shellcodes. Only .text section is allowed. In fact the solution is a 'JMP rel16 Jump near' like jmp $-4242 gives 'E969EFFFFF'. Thank you very much. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to emit a specific sequence of bytes (e9 and some zeros) into the code, then you can use db.

Comment: Hello thank you very much for your answer. I've just tried with another technique very close to yours with the following code : TCHAR 233;
dword 00000000; It's not very biautiful but it generates the 'E900000000' opcode. But are you sure there is no jmp 'E9' with MASM32 ? It's very strange. It would be better.

Answer (score 0):

'E9' opcode has 'jump short' command

- http://read.seas.harvard.edu/cs261/hwref/i386/JMP.htm
- http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/2bytejumps.htm

If you define 'label', somewhere near 'jmp' instruction (withing range -128…127 bytes), then you could write something like this:

```
jmp short label
label:
```

If you want to jump to address 0x00000000, then you could use this construction, but the opcode of jmp (in general case) will not be equal to 'E9':

```
org 0
label0:

...
jmp label0
```

Comment: Yes I have already tried this and this opcode is 'EB'. Thank you anyway.

Comment: user1364743, it's my inaccuracy. 'jump near' not 'jump short' has 'E9' opcode.

Comment: anyway, if you want to manually replace some bytes after compilation, then you could choose any magic sequence of bytes and define it using 'db' (as Will Dean proposed).